# Vue: Do computed properties watch for internal data changes?

Tags: vue.js

I am passing in `products` as a prop to this component.  I am then setting a data value to those props because I am going to be pushing products to it.
In my template, I am using a computed property `productsToShow` because if a prop `hideSoldOutProducts` is passed in, they get filtered out.

My question is:  I made `productsData` a data value because at the bottom of the page, their will be an API call to push more products to the `productsData` array.  So although the `productsData` is being added to, the computed property `productsToShow()` which is using the `productsData` is not reflecting this.

```
<template>
    <div v-for="(product, index) in productsToShow">
      .....
    </div>
</template>
```

---

```
data() {
    return {
        productsData:       Vue.util.extend([], this.products.data)
    }
},
props: {
    products:            {type: Object},
    hideSoldOutProducts: {type: Boolean}
},
computed: {
    productsToShow() {
        if (!this.products.data) {
            return []
        }

        if (this.hideSoldOutProducts) {
            let filteredList = this.productsData.filter(x => x.product.inventory_quantity.quantity > 1)
            return filteredList
        } else {
            return this.productsData
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you adding products to `productsData`?

Comment: I `this.productsData = response.data.data` in the success part of the API call so I can see `this.productsData` having more data added to it in the Vue devtools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It feels like there might be a better approach, since this looks quite complex. But perhaps the reactivity is not working because the data is only set on mount. You could set a watcher on your property and bind the new property data to productsData on a change.

But, I have the feeling that it might be a better approach to create an `addProduct` methods that will push a product into you data array. Something like this.

```
watcher: {
    products(value) {
        value.data.forEach(this.addProduct);
    }
},
methods: {
    addProduct(product) {
       // here you could also check if the product already exists in your 
       // productsData
       this.productsData.unshift(product);
    },
    fetchProducts() {
        this.$http.get('/api/products')
                  .then(resp => {
                      // Now we can loop through and add the products.
                      resp.data.forEach(this.addProduct);
                  });
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.